# The wiki editor generates a link "Template:Multiple Image" (to a page that does not exist) when I try to use the multiple image template

Tags: wiki

I am editing a wiki and I want to insert multiple images thanks to the [{{multiple image}} template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Multiple_image). Here is my code:

```
{{multiple image
| footer = foo
| image1 = foo1.png
| caption1 = foo 1
| image2 = foo2.jpg
| caption2 = foo 2
}}
```

However this code generates a link `Template:Multiple Image` to a page that does not exist.

I obviously read the [wiki documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Multiple_image) and looked for an answer on the web and on stackoverflow but I could find nothing about this bug. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you editing en.wikipedia.org, that has a template called 'multiple image', or are you editing a different site with no such template?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and assume the template needs to be added. Will let you know if I find a solution.